# Best way to abstract season/show/episode data

Tags: python, data-structures

Basically, I've written an API to www.thetvdb.com in Python. The current code can be found [here](http://github.com/dbr/tvdb_api/tree/master/tvdb_api.py).

It grabs data from the API as requested, and has to store the data somehow, and make it available by doing:

```
print tvdbinstance[1][23]['episodename'] # get the name of episode 23 of season 1
```

What is the "best" way to abstract this data within the `Tvdb()` class?

I originally used a extended `Dict()` that automatically created sub-dicts (so you could do `x[1][2][3][4] = "something"` without having to do `if x[1].has_key(2): x[1][2] = []` and so on)

Then I just stored the data by doing `self.data[show_id][season_number][episode_number][attribute_name] = "something"`

This worked okay, but there was no easy way of checking if `x[3][24]` was supposed to exist or not (so I couldn't raise the season_not_found exception).

Currently it's using four classes: `ShowContainer`, `Show`, `Season` and `Episode`. Each one is a very basic dict, which I can easily add extra functionality in (the `search()` function on `Show()` for example). Each has a `__setitem__`, `__getitem_` and `has_key`.

This works mostly fine, I can check in Shows if it has that season in it's `self.data` dict, if not, `raise season_not_found`. I can also check in `Season()` if it has that episode and so on.

The problem now is it's presenting itself as a dict, but doesn't have all the functionality, and because I'm overriding the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` functions, it's easy to accidentally recursively call `__getitem__` (so I'm not sure if extending the `Dict` class will cause problems).

The other slight problem is adding data into the dict is a lot more work than the old `Dict` method (which was `self.data[seas_no][ep_no]['attribute'] = 'something'`). See `_setItem` and `_setData`. It's not too bad, since it's currently only a read-only API interface (so the users of the API should only ever retrieve data, not add more), but it's hardly... Elegant.

I think the series-of-classes system is probably the best way, but does anyone have a better idea for storing the data? And would extending the `ShowContainer`/etc classes with `Dict` cause problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, what you need is `classobj` from new module. That would allow you to construct exception classes dynamically (`classobj` takes a string as an argument for the class name).

```
import new
myexc=new.classobj("ExcName",(Exception,),{})
i=myexc("This is the exc msg!")
raise i
```

this gives you:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
__main__.ExcName: This is the exc msg!
```

remember that you can always get the class name through:

```
self.__class__.__name__
```

So, after some string mangling and concatenation, you should be able to obtain appropriate exception class name and construct a class object using that name and then raise that exception.

P.S. - you can also raise strings, but this is deprecated.

```
raise(self.__class__.__name__+"Exception")
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not use SQLite? There is good support in Python and you can write SQL queries to get the data out. Here is the Python docs for [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-sqlite3.html)

---

If you don't want to use SQLite you could do an array of dicts.

```
episodes = []
episodes.append({'season':1, 'episode': 2, 'name':'Something'})
episodes.append({'season':1, 'episode': 2, 'name':'Something', 'actors':['Billy Bob', 'Sean Penn']})
```

That way you add metadata to any record and search it very easily

```
season_1 = [e for e in episodes if e['season'] == 1]
billy_bob = [e for e in episodes if 'actors' in e and 'Billy Bob' in e['actors']]

for episode in billy_bob:
    print "Billy bob was in Season %s Episode %s" % (episode['season'], episode['episode'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in the past and used an in-memory XML document as a quick and dirty hierarchical database for storage. You can store each show/season/episode as an element (nested appropriately) and attributes of these things as xml attributes on the elements. Then you can use XQuery to get info back out.

**NOTE:** I'm not a Python guy so I don't know what your xml support is like.

**NOTE 2:** You'll want to profile this because it'll be bigger and slower than the solution you've already got. Likely enough if you are doing some high-volume processing then XML is probably not going to be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get this part here:

> This worked okay, but there was no easy way of checking if x[3][24] was supposed to exist or not (so I couldn't raise the season_not_found exception)

There is a way to do it - called **in**:

```
>>>x={}
>>>x[1]={}
>>>x[1][2]={}
>>>x
{1: {2: {}}}
>>> 2 in x[1]
True
>>> 3 in x[1]
False
```

what seems to be the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

Bartosz/To clarify "This worked okay, but there was no easy way of checking if x[3][24] was supposed to exist or not"

`x['some show'][3][24]` would return season 3, episode 24 of "some show". If there was no season 3, I want the pseudo-dict to raise tvdb_seasonnotfound, if "some show" doesn't exist, then raise tvdb_shownotfound

The current system of a series of classes, each with a `__getitem__` - Show checks `if self.seasons.has_key(requested_season_number)`, the Season class checks `if self.episodes.has_key(requested_episode_number)` and so on.

It works, but it there seems to be a lot of repeated code (each class is basically the same, but raises a different error)